# Java:File name sent as string,file not being found

Tags: java, file

I am trying to read from another file(`text1.txt`) and write (the contents of `text1.txt`) into another(`text2.txt`).

I send these two names as `args[0]` and `args[1]`.

I must specify that both file are in my src folder of the project and yet I get the `FileNotFoundException`,and yes I tried with `getAbsolutePath()` and yet I get the same exception.

This is my code:

```
public class Test4 {

  public void write(String s,String s2) throws Exception
  {
    File _filein=new File(s);
    File _fileout=new File(s2);
    _fileout.createNewFile();
    PrintWriter _prw=new PrintWriter(_fileout);
    BufferedWriter _buffwrt=new BufferedWriter(_prw);
    FileInputStream _readfrom=new FileInputStream(_filein.getAbsolutePath());
    BufferedReader _read=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_readfrom));
    String _str=_read.readLine();
    while(_str!=null)
    {
        _buffwrt.write(_str+" ");
        _buffwrt.flush();
        _str=_read.readLine();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Test4 T4=new Test4();
    T4.write(args[0],args[1]);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Try to put it outside `src` folder. It should at project level

Comment: @Parth  thank you ,that worked smoothly.I didn't even think that this was the problem.

Comment: Default context path for eclipse is at project level. So, referencing file as `new File("test.txt")` would be referring to project level folder which is parent folder of `src`

Answer (score 0):

Manually reading & writing files is always problematic - you should'nt do that unless you know EXACTLY what type of content you're reading/writing and how it is to be aligned. It is **much** easier to copy files and let the API do all of that work : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

> Copy a file to a target file. This method copies a file to the target
>   file with the options parameter specifying how the copy is performed.
>   By default, the copy fails if the target file already exists or is a
>   symbolic link, except if the source and target are the same file, in
>   which case the method completes without copying the file. File
>   attributes are not required to be copied to the target file. If
>   symbolic links are supported, and the file is a symbolic link, then
>   the final target of the link is copied. If the file is a directory
>   then it creates an empty directory in the target location (entries in
>   the directory are not copied). This method can be used with the
>   walkFileTree method to copy a directory and all entries in the
>   directory, or an entire file-tree where required.